# How to get the check box selected position

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, listadapter, android-checkbox

How to get the selected position in checkbox itemId.

I have two item Veg and non-veg item. I want the result for veg Items only. I show the screen in veg items .But it is not working for veg list checked items.

Response

```
|1|Amaretto cookies|True
```

1. is itemId
2. food item
3. True/False.

Based on True or False I need to check the check boxes and retrieve the checked items

**Veg items**:

```
|21|1|Amaretto cookies|True|2|Amish White Bread|True|6|Caesar Salad|True|10|Guacamole|True|13|Macaroni and Cheese|True|16|Pancakes|True|17|Pasta|True|18|Ribollita|True|20|Pizza|True|21|Seven Layer Taco Dip|True|22|Shrimp Bisque|True|23|Spicy Bean Salsa|True|24|Sopapilla Cheesecake|True|25|Sopapilla Cheesecake Pie|True|26|Vegetarian Tortilla Stew|True|561|food|True|563|asdf|True|574|veg|True|579|a|True|593|hjg|True|619|hhy|True|
```

**Non- Veg items**:

```
|12|3|Barbeque|False|4|Buffalo Chicken Wings|False|5|Burgers|False|7|Classic Lasagna|False|8|Chicken Chow Mein|False|9|Fried Chicken|False|11|Japanese sushi|False|12|Mezze|False|14|Mutton Pepper Gravy|False|15|Paella Valenciana|False|19|Phad Thai Recipe|False|578|Pizza|False|
```

**Url**:

```
  String user_url="http://mobileapps.iwedplanner.com/mobileapps/iwedplanner/mobile/version21/mmealitems.aspx?uname="+LoginForm.str1+"&occasion="+occasionval;
```

**Code:**

```
    httpclass obj = new httpclass();
    result = obj.server_conn(user_url);
    System.out.println(result);
    if (result != null) 
    {           
        token = new StringTokenizer2(result, "");
    }
        value = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (token.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {
            value.add(token.nextToken());
        }   

        value.add(Integer.toString(value.size()));

        Integer k=null; 
        table=new Hashtable<Integer,ArrayList<String>>();
        itemId = new ArrayList<String>();   
        stritem = new ArrayList<String>();
        vegitems = new ArrayList<String>();
        nonvegitems = new ArrayList<String>();

        int id=0,c=0,n=value.size();

        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {               
             z = value.get(j);

        String[] mystring  = z.split("<br>");

            int arraysize = mystring.length;

            for(int a=0; a<arraysize-1;a++)
            {

                str2.add(mystring[0]);

                str3.add(mystring[1]);
            }

        }

        for(int g=0; g<str2.size();g++)
        {               
            String name = str2.get(g);

            token2 = new StringTokenizer2(name, "|", false);

            while (token2.hasMoreTokens()) 
            {
            vegitems.add(token2.nextToken());
            }

        }

        for(int x=1;x<vegitems.size();x++)
        {   
            itemId.add(vegitems.get(x));
            x=x+1;

            stritem.add(vegitems.get(x));
            x=x+1;

            status.add(vegitems.get(x));

        }                           
        setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter(this));
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tru = new StringBuffer();
                fals = new StringBuffer();

                for (int i = 0; i<status.size();i++) 
                {
                    if (status.get(i).equals("True"))

                        tru.append(itemId.get(i)+",");
                    else
                        fals.append(itemId.get(i)+",");
                }

                boolean netvalue = false;
                 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


                    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    if (info != null && info.isAvailable()) {
                                            String user_url="http://mobileapps.iwedplanner.com/mobileapps/iwedplanner/mobile/version21/minsertmealchoiceNew.aspx?uname="+username+"&occasion="+occasionval+
                            "&choice="+tru+fals+"&ownchoice=&category=";

                    httpclass obj = new httpclass();
                    result = obj.server_conn(user_url);

                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(result, "|");
                    result = st.nextToken();

                    if ((result.equals("Engagement 1&")) || (result.equals("Wedding 1&")) || (result.equals("Reception 1&"))) 
                    {


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter 
{
    Activity context;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    IconicAdapter(Activity context)                    
    {
        super(context, R.layout.rsvp_mealsse, stritem);

        this.context = context;
    }

@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rsvp_mealsse,null);//viewappointlist, null);

        TextView index = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.index);
        index.setText(String.valueOf(position+1)+".");


        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        label.setText(stritem.get(position));


        CheckBox check=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);

        check.setId(Integer.parseInt(itemId.get(position)));


        if(status.get(position).equals("True"))
             check.setChecked(true);


            else
             check.setChecked(false);


                check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        int ind=itemId.indexOf(String.valueOf(buttonView.getId()));
                        status.set(ind, String.valueOf(isChecked));

                    }

                });


        return (row);

}
}
```

**Snap :**

This is what it should look like.False items are checked in the snap

[image]

Above shows the full code of my project.

**These are my requirements**:

It is all about event planner for Food. The invited guests can select and save the interested food items such as `pizza`, `Caesar salad`, `Ameretocokies` etc from the items list and mail to the inviter so that the inviter can view the saved items and arrange for the selected items.

Comment: you need checked items list right?

Comment: What do you want, a list of item which is checked???

Comment: Does my post not help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I picked the solution from Romain Guy's solution  @

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/No0LrgJ6q2M

I have used a `ViewHolder` pattern for smooth scrolling and performance. I have used a `SparseBooleanArray` to get checked items.

I assume you want the items whose corresponding check boxes are checked.

Also check this to understand listview re-cycles views

[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

```
public class dsds extends Activity
{

    ListView lv;
    String result = null;
    StringTokenizer2 token = null,token2=null;;

    ArrayList<String> value,value2 = null; 
    ArrayList<String> str = null;
    ArrayList<String> str2 = null;
    ArrayList<String> newstatus=null;
    Hashtable<Integer, String> checkstatus=null;
    ArrayList<String>stateId=null;
    StringBuffer tru,fals;
    private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
    String z;
    ArrayList<Holder> ha = new ArrayList<Holder>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.text);
         str2 = new ArrayList<String>();        
         stateId = new ArrayList<String>(); 
         newstatus=new ArrayList<String>();
         lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
           Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
           new TheTask().execute();
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i=0;i<str2.size();i++)
                    {
                        if(mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                        {
                            result.append(str2.get(i));
                            result.append("\n");
                        }

                }
                Toast.makeText(dsds.this, result, 1000).show();
                }

            });
     }   
    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://mobileapps.iwedplanner.com/mobileapps/iwedplanner/mobile/version21/mmealitems.aspx?uname=abcdefg&occasion=Engagement");

            try
            {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

                if (_response != null) 
                {
                    //alertbox("",result);
                     String[] mystring  = _response.split("<br>"); // splt by break
                     token = new StringTokenizer2(mystring[0], "|", false);// split by |
                     token2 = new StringTokenizer2(mystring[1], "|", false);
                }
             ///////    for veg
                    value = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while (token.hasMoreTokens()) 
                    {
                        value.add(token.nextToken());

                    }


                    for(int i=1;i<value.size()-1;i=i+3)
                    {

                   //   Log.i("....Veg ids.......",""+value.get(i));
                        stateId.add(value.get(i));
                    }
                    for(int i=2;i<value.size()-1;i=i+3)
                    {
                        str2.add(value.get(i));
                  //    Log.i("....Veg ids.......",""+value.get(i));
                    }
                    for(int i=3;i<=value.size()-1;i=i+3)
                    {
                        newstatus.add(value.get(i));
                //      Log.i("....Veg ids.......",""+value.get(i));
                    }
                // add all to list of Holder

                  for(int h=0;h<str2.size();h++)
                  {
                    Holder holder = new Holder();
                    holder.setTitle(str2.get(h));
                    holder.setId(stateId.get(h));
                    if(newstatus.get(h).equals("False"))
                    {
                        holder.setCheck(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        holder.setCheck(false);
                    }
                    ha.add(holder);
                  }


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            lv.setAdapter(new IconicAdapter(dsds.this));
        }

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {
        Activity context;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        IconicAdapter(Activity context)                    
        {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, str2);
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(str2.size());
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

    @Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
       ViewHolder holder;
       if(convertView==null)
       {
           convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
           holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
           convertView.setTag(holder);
       }
       else
       {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }
          Holder hol = ha.get(position);
          holder.tv1.setText(hol.getId().toString());
          holder.tv2.setText(hol.getTitle().toString());
          if(hol.isCheck()==true)
          {
          holder.cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, true));
          holder.cb.setTag(position);

          }
          else
          {
          holder.cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
          holder.cb.setTag(position);

          }
          holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        return convertView;

    }

     public boolean isChecked(int position) {
         return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
     }

     public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
         mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

     }

     public void toggle(int position) {
         setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

     }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {

         mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);    
    }

}
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tv1,tv2;
        CheckBox cb;
    }
}
```

Holder class

```
public class Holder {

    String title;
    String id;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    boolean check;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public boolean isCheck() {
        return check;
    }
    public void setCheck(boolean check) {
        this.check = check;
    }

}
```

text.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_above="@id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

list_tiem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

Now 1 and 2 are checked and when you click the button at the bottom you see the selected text. I checked 1 and 2 manually. However it depends on the response ie True or False. Right now all veg items are true.

Note: The list displays only veg items

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using list-view and you want to check list-view item then you can use below code.

```
int len = mListView.getCount();
SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
if (checked.get(i)){
..... // Your code whatever you want to do with selected item..
}
else{
.... 
}
```

Comment: Hope this will help you, and still if you are facing any error then let me know.